# autoNumeric plugin error in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently using autoNumeric in my application. 
It works great. 
However, in edit mode, JQuery is showing this error message:

***The value ($ 100.000.00) being 'set' is not numeric and has caused a error to be thrown***

I've something like this:

```
public string Amount { get; set; }

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.Amount, ViewData).Watermark })

$.extend($.fn.autoNumeric.defaults, {
            aSep: '@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator',
            aDec: '@System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator'
        });

$("#Amount").autoNumeric('init', { aSign: "$ " });
```

I have search for the error and found [this](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/issues/143)

but that didn't help me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens if you remove the space after the `$` sign?

Comment: that didn't work. same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I enter the value, during creation it is entered as $ 100,000.00
and that is save to the database just like that.

However, I have updated my code to remove the symbols before saving.

```
var amount = String.Join("", model.Amount.Split('$', ','));
```

So if $ 100,000.00 is entered, it is saved as 100000.00

and that fixed the issue.